# How can ı reach the pandas dataframe value count in row?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
   edu_data.loc[edu_data.gender == 'M'][["gender", "Class"]].value_counts()
```

[image]

Here is my output.

I made this example for all columns in my dataset.

```
for i in edu_data[class_haric].columns: 
    
    kolonun_nunique_sayisi = edu_data[i].nunique()
    
    for j in range(kolonun_nunique_sayisi): 
        t = pd.DataFrame(edu_data.loc[edu_data[i] == edu_data.loc[:,i].unique()[j]][[i, "Class"]])
        print(t.value_counts(), "\n")
```

some of the output results

[image]

I want to reach every single value in example;
Just i must reach M --- > 50 L---> 37 ... after that as below M ---> 23 , H ---> 22 ...
How can i reach(ex:print is enough for me) them all the datas ?

Comment: `df.groupby(["gender", "Class"])['Class'].count()`?

Comment: @It_is_Chris its give me the same result